# Merge two tables if groupby argument falls in an interval (non equi join in R)

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have the following two tables:

```
df <- data.table(id = c("01","02","03"), tariff = c("1A","1B","1A"), summer = c(0,0,1), expenditure = c(150,200,90))
   id tariff summer expenditure
1: 01     1A      0         150
2: 02     1B      0         200
3: 03     1A      1          90

catalogue <- data.table(tariff = c("1A","1A","1A","1A","1B","1B","1B","1B"), summer = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                        lb_quant = c(0,50,0,80,0,80,0,100), ub_quant = c(50,Inf,80,Inf,80,Inf,100,Inf), case = letters[1:8])
   tariff summer lb_quant ub_quant case
1:     1A      0        0       50    a
2:     1A      0       50      Inf    b
3:     1A      1        0       80    c
4:     1A      1       80      Inf    d
5:     1B      0        0       80    e
6:     1B      0       80      Inf    f
7:     1B      1        0      100    g
8:     1B      1      100      Inf    h
```

I want to merge `df` and `catalogue` by `tariff`, `summer` and `expenditure`. However, `expenditure` is numeric, so merging will not work directly.

I'm looking for a vectorized way to merge the two tables together if:

1. `tariff` and `summer` match
2. `catalogue$lb_quant < df$expenditure <= catalogue$ub_quant`

As an example, I would like to match `df[id == "01"]` with the second line of `catalogue` because `tariff == "01"` and `summer == 0` and `expenditure` falls within `[50, inf)`. So assign `case = b` to `df[id = "01"]`.

The real `df` is huge and I want to avoid using loops. Is there a vectorized way to achieve this in R or Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use a non-equi update join in this case.

See the following one-liner (added linebreaks for readability)

```
df[ catalogue, 
    `:=`( lb_quant = i.lb_quant, 
          ub_quant= i.ub_quant, 
          case = i.case ),
    on = .( tariff, 
            summer, 
            expenditure > lb_quant, 
            expenditure < ub_quant ) ][]
```

**output**

```
   id tariff summer expenditure lb_quant ub_quant case
1: 01     1A      0         150       50      Inf    b
2: 02     1B      0         200       80      Inf    f
3: 03     1A      1          90       80      Inf    d
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the syntax please? I had never seen `:=` wrapped in ticks. Also, what does `i.column` mean?

Comment: In this above data-table syntax, the `i` references the data-table you want to join to `df`. So `i = catalogue` (sort of). the `:=` between ticks is a way to add multiple columns in one go (by reference). so `lb_quant` is a newly created column, based on the values in `i.lb_quant` (which is actually `catalogue$lb_quant`). In the section after `on =` the keys to join on are given. `tariff` and `summer` exist in both `df` and `catalogue` and are matched equi. `expenditure` is matched non-equi to the `lb_quant/ub_quant` columns from `catalogue`.

Comment: Inline operators (e.g., `%in%`, `<-`, `units<-`, and yes, `:=`) are just special functions. The way to use an inline operator as a "normal function" is to enclose it in back-ticks. So `df[, a := 1]` is identical to `df[, \`:=\`("a", 1)]` (in `data.table`, you actually don't need the quotes, but outside of that you typically do).

Comment: +1 Wimpel, I often forget that `data.table`'s merge is much more like SQL's joins in that it can handle inequalities, unlike R's base `merge`, nice.

Answer (score 4):

`data.table::foverlaps` does merging with intervals in two tables. To do that, you need to

1. ensure both tables have the intervals defined; in the case where only one column is defined, you need to explicitly copy that to a new field, thereby creating intervals of 0 (it seems odd, but it is minor and temporary);
2. set table keys to include (in order): joining keys, then the interval columns

```r
df[, exp2 := expenditure]
setkey(df, tariff, summer, expenditure, exp2)
setkey(catalogue, tariff, summer, lb_quant, ub_quant)
foverlaps(df, catalogue)
#    tariff summer lb_quant ub_quant case id expenditure exp2
# 1:     1A      0       50      Inf    b 01         150  150
# 2:     1A      1       80      Inf    d 03          90   90
# 3:     1B      0       80      Inf    f 02         200  200
```

(after the merge, you can remove keys and the extra columns if desired)

Comment: Do you mean I have to have the intervals that each expenditure corresponds to defined in `df` before? I don't understand point number one :/

Comment: Your `df` has *one number* that is intended to fit into the `catalogue`'s *two numbers*. The `foverlaps` function requires that both tables have two columns, intending to check for various types of overlap, including `"any"` and `"within"`. So while you want the logic of `a >= b1 & a <= b2`, this function checks for `a1 >= b1 & a2 <= b2` (for `"within"`). So you need two columns in both frames, even if you want the intuitively-simple `"within"`. See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.2/topics/foverlaps

Comment: This means that while you want to test for `expenditure >= lb_quant & expenditure <= ub_quant`, you need to tell `foverlaps` to test for `expenditure >= lb_quant & exp2 <= ub_quant`, where `expenditure` and `exp2` are identical. It's a formality only (in this case).